# InputStreams Cascade closing

Tags: java

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("filepath"));
...
read from bis
...
bis.close();
```

i didnt close FileInputStream, Can BufferedInputStream's close() function close FileInputStream?
or is there any memory problem?

thanks...

Comment: `close()` ever closes the associated channel or InputStream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can BufferedInputStream's close()
>   function close FileInputStream?

Yes. `Java IO` classes are based on [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) Pattern.

> is there any memory problem?

`No`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `BufferedInputStream.close()` does close the `InputStream` instance passed through the constructor.